# Cannot Animate a Polygon Created by a Function in SVG.JS

Tags: svg.js

I've written a JavaScript function that creates a triangle (MyFirstTriangle). The triangle displays perfectly as one would expect. However, when I try to apply an animation to the triangle I get the "ReferenceError: MyFirstTriangle is not defined".

```
function CreateTriangle(Name) {

var Name = draw.polygon("50 15, 100 100, 0 100").fill("#fff").stroke({ width: 0 })

 }

CreateTriangle("MyFirstTriangle");

MyFirstTriangle.animate(4000, '<>', 500 * i).rotate(30 * i);
```

When I create the same triangle directly (as in, not through a function), then the animation works perfectly. Are there some inherent limitations regarding the use of functions with SVG.JS?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how programming works.
You call the function `CreateTriangle` with the Parameter `MyFirstTriangle` but you are not using this parameter in the function. Instead you are creating a new local variable with the name `Name` which overwrites the parameter you passed.
Whatever you save in `Name` is then lost at the end of the function because you return nothing.

A working example would work somehow like this:

```js
function CreateTriangle() {

   return draw.polygon("50 15, 100 100, 0 100").fill("#fff").stroke({ width: 0 })

 }

const MyFirstTriangle = CreateTriangle();

MyFirstTriangle.animate(4000, '<>', 500 * i).rotate(30 * i);
```